# Runtime Error using ViewModelProvider(this) in AppCompatActivity

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use a ViewModelProvider for an android dynamic-feature library, which is being added to an existing project. I have the following code in my AppCompatActivity class.

```
MyModel model = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyModel.class);
```

The project is using the 2.2.0 version of the androidx lifecycle libraries. From my gradle file:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"

    // ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$lifecycle_version"
```

I am getting the following error at runtime.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Landroidx/lifecycle/ViewModelStoreOwner;)V in class Landroidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider' appears in.....apk
```

Is this a bug? Do I have some dependency issue with something already in the larger app? How would I track down the dependency issue if it is somehow using an older version of ViewModelProvider from the existing app? I would have thought by naming the explicit version of the dependency in my gradle file, it would avoid such conflicts.

Comment: Did you found the solution for this problem?

Comment: hi @Derek did you manage to find a solution for this.. I am having similar problem..

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I don't know why but it works well when I use the deprecated class `ViewModelProviders`.

```
MyModel model = new ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyModel.class);
```